# Create a root element in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an input document, where I only want to extract the elements with the prefix `ppp`. All elements with the prefix `ppp` are on the same level.

**Input:**

```
<root>
   <ppp:element>aaa</ppp:element>
   <ppp:element>ccc</ppp:element>
   <lala:element>PPP</lala:element>
   <rrr:element>dsfsdbfsdf</rrr:element>
</root>
```

In my XSLT I copy all the elements with the prefix `ppp` to the output file.

The problem is that I don't have a `root` element in the output file.

So I need to create a `root` element. And inside the `root` element, I should copy all element with the prefix `ppp`.

**My XSLT:**

```
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ppp:*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ppp:*/node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<root>
   <ppp:element>aaa</ppp:element>
   <ppp:element>ccc</ppp:element>
</root>
```

Comment: That cannot be your input: you cannot have a prefix without binding it to a namespace. Same applies to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Given a **well-formed** input, all your stylesheet would have to do is:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ppp:*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic option to discard all elements, no matter where they are in the XML tree, if they have the `ppp` prefix (regardless of the namespace URI – this is bad practice! But it's strictly what you're asking for), while preserving the root of the input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ppp="http://example.org">

  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="/|@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[substring-before(name(), ':') != 'ppp' and not(. = /)]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the XSLT transform demo: http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3y/2.

Answer (score -1):

Thnx.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ppp:name>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </ppp:name>

</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ppp:*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ppp:*/node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

The above works for me :)

Comment: This does not provide the requested output. It does not copy the text nodes contained in `ppp:element` nodes - but it does copy all other text nodes from the entire XML input.